# Header style datagrid silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I am using silverlight and cant edit the header style of the data grid.

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
    </Style>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

It's written that member `FontSize` and `Background` are not accessible.

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to:

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <Style xmlns:primitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data" 
           TargetType="primitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
    </Style>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

It should allow you set the properties with that namespace and target type added. You could also just add the namespace to the user control, instead of putting it in the style.